# What are the two errors in my program?

Tags: java

Can you help me to determine the error here ?
Please please can you fix it please

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Loan_payment
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      double inst=0.4, loan_amt=0.56, pay=0.34;   
      double mon = (inst/1200);
      double quarterly = (inst/400);
      double Half = (inst/200);
      double annual = (inst/100);

     //Mothly
     double ad = 1 + mon;      
     double amt,amt_mon,amt2; 
     amt_mon = -1*((Math.log( 1 - ((mon * loan_amt) / pay))));
     amt2 =(Math.log(ad));
     amt = (amt_mon / amt2);
     System.out.println("Number of Payments based on monthly : "+amt);

     //Quarterly
     ad = 1 + quarterly;
     double amt_quart;
     amt_quart = (( -Math.log( 1 - ((quarterly * loan_amt) / pay))));
     amt = (amt_quart / amt2);
     System.out.println("Number of Payments based on quarterly : "+amt);

     //HalfYearly
     ad = 1 + Half;
     double amt_half;
     amt_half = (( -Math.log( 1 - ((Half * loan_amt) / pay))));
     amt = (amt_half / amt2);
     System.out.println("Number of Payments based on HalfYearly : "+amt);

     //Annually
     ad = 1 + annual;
     double amt_ann;
     amt_ann = (( -Math.log( 1 - ((annual * loan_amt) / pay))));
     amt = (amt_ann / amt2);
     System.out.println("Number of Payments based on Annually : "+amt);
  }
}
```

Can you help me to determine the error here?

Comment: Well you need to explain what the error is. Then people can help find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

No errors whatsoever, giving output :-

```
Number of Payments based on monthly : 1.6477856928143282
Number of Payments based on quarterly : 4.94607431098997
Number of Payments based on HalfYearly : 9.900315277456814
Number of Payments based on Annually : 19.833405363765696
```